# Clearing canvas save animations already running

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, canvas

I am trying to learn 2d canvas animations but cannot figure out how to keep animations already created running.

For example: on click i create a circle that runs to the top left of the screen, but when I click again that animation is cleared and a new one starts. I want more than one circle running at a time.

code:

```
window.requestAnimFrame=(function(callback){
    return window.requestAnimationFrame||window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame||window.mozRequestAnimationFrame||window.oRequestAnimationFrame||window.msRequestAnimationFrame||function(callback){
        window.setTimeout(callback,1000/60);
    };
})();

var can = $('canvas')[0],
    ctx = can.getContext('2d'),
    width = window.innerWidth,
    height = window.innerHeight-5,
    color = '';

can.width = width;
can.height = height;
can.addEventListener('click',randomColor);
can.addEventListener('click',animate);

var circle = {
    x:0,
    y:0,
    r:5,
    d:2*Math.PI,
    color:''
}

function drawCircle(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circle.x,circle.y,circle.r,0,circle.d,false);
    ctx.fillStyle = circle.color;
    ctx.fill();
}

function randomColor(){
    color = 'rgba('+Math.floor(Math.random()*255)+','+Math.floor(Math.random()*255)+','+Math.floor(Math.random()*255)+',1)';
}

function clear(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,can.width,can.height);
}

function animate(event,startTime){
    if(startTime==undefined){
        startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    }
    circle.x = event.clientX;
    circle.y = event.clientY;
    circle.color = color;
    var time = (new Date()).getTime()-startTime;
    var speed = (300*time/1000);
    circle.x += speed;
    circle.y -= speed;
    if (circle.x+circle.r>width||circle.y<0||circle.y>height||circle.x<0) {
        return;
    }
    clear();
    drawCircle();
    requestAnimFrame(function(){
        animate(event,startTime);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I don't think the clearing of the canvas is the problem.*

How I would approach it:

Make `circle` into an object instead of an variable.

Now make a new function `addCircle()` which creates a new circle object and adds it to your canvas and to a list of circles (you can use your `drawCircle()` function in here).

Modify your `animate()` function so that it iterates through your new list of circles, thereby moving each one.

This should at least get you on track.